# Extension Host Terminated Unexpectedly on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

So, I've been getting an error on my **visual-studio-code** saying that the **extension host terminated unexpectedly**:

[image: error as image]

When I opened my dev tools to view the problem, this is what I see:

[image: console output]

As well as *this* when I scroll down:

[image: big error in console]

I read somewhere here where someone mentioned that their extension host problem was fixed when they disabled the live server. I tried that and it did not work for me.

For what it's worth, I can still code, but this extension host terminating is stopping my intellisense and a lot of my auto-complete codes.

Also (and, I'm not sure if this also has something to do with my live server), but I've been having problems opening my default browser lately.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thank-you.

I tried disabling my live server (someone on Stack Overflow mentioned they had the same problem and disabling the live server fixed it), but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few errors with some of your extensions, I think the one causing you the biggest issue is this extension (or something similar with omi snippets): React/Redux/Typescript/Javascript/Omi snippets - try disabling this extension

Comment: Thank you SO much, Brian! I disabled/uninstalled the React/Redux/Typescript/Javascript/Omi snippets extension ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wscats.omi-snippets&ssr=false#review-details ) and my extension host hasn't terminated so far!

Again, thank you so much for your help.

If you don't mind me asking, how did you know that the extension host termination was due to that extension? When I went to the dev tools, I just saw a debugger error and then a whole bunch of "red errors".

Comment: No problem @dho115, I'm from nucamp as well btw(you should hop in the discord). You are able to make out some of the errors because it shows the extension name, or some other identifier that can be used. You have a few other errors which aren't causing any major issues, so they can just be ignored. However, a big chunk of error code like that is probably going to be problematic - and you can typically look at one of the first few lines or one of the last few lines to figure out what is actually causing the issue. In this case, the first line has omi-snippets so I figured it was that extension.